# get client IP for an MQTT request over haproxy

Tags: ssl, mqtt, haproxy

I've configured `X_FORWARDED_FOR` to capture client IP for a HTTPS request and it works as expected.

However, for MQTT, the data is sent over SSL and HTTP/S does not come into the picture.

```
ssl://<HOST_NAME>:<PORT>
```

I've tried adding the following to the backend server on HAproxy config. No luck so far.

```
backend TestServer
    mode tcp
    server TestServer01 10.6.186.24:48080 send-proxy-v2
------
    server TestServer01 10.6.186.24:48080 send-proxy
------    
    server TestServer01 10.6.186.24:48080 send-proxy-v2-ssl
```

Is there a way to capture client (source) IP for an incoming MQTT request by changing HAProxy configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no where in the MQTT protocol to store the original client IP address (like adding extra headers to HTTP requests).

The proxy is literally just forwarding packets that arrive on it's public port to the backend servers (with the possible exception of doing SSL termination) it doesn't change the packets at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the IP address to do stick-table based abuse protection, you will need to key your stick-table with the MQTT client identifier.

For example this will reject clients if their connection rate is greater than 1 per second, over a 10s window.

```
tcp-request content set-var(txn.client_id) req.payload(0,0),mqtt_field_value(connect,client_identifier) if data_in_buffer
stick-table type string len 64 size 100k expire 5m store gpc0,gpc0_rate(10s)
tcp-request content track-sc0 var(txn.client_id)
tcp-request content sc-inc-gpc0(0)
tcp-request content reject if { sc0_gpc0_rate gt 10 }
```